# Ajax request passing variable and asks DB for WHERE = variable

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

This is my AJAX call:

```
function ck_loader() {
    row_count = $('.grid-item').length || 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseURL + "welcome/load_more",
        data: {offset: row_count, numbdata: permaData},
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (response) { 
            if (response === "") {
                $grid.packery();
            }
        } else {
            var $response = $(response);
            $(".grid").append($response);
            $grid.packery( 'addItems', $response);
            $grid.packery(); 
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        //alert("ERROR");

    }
});
```

so offset counts number of elements (rows) that are visable at the moment, and it helps control the offset of database (loading 15 elements per call)

`numbdata: permaData` is a variable where I'm saving the filter selection, so my menu has a filter selection, and data from there is saved in a variable (when someone press "video" filter, it saves "video" inside of `permaData`)

It connects to:

```
public function load_more()
{
    $offset = $this->input->post('offset');
    if($offset)
    {
        $new_rows = $this->postovi_model->get_next_10($offset);
        if(isset($new_rows))
        {
            $data['users'] = $new_rows;
            //this will return (echo) html to the ajax success function
            //CI takes care of making the correct response headers - sweet
            $this->load->view('user_rows_view', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            echo ""; //return an empty string
        }
    }
}
```

There is a model included in this PHP script:

```
public function get_next_10($offset = 0)
{
    $this->db->limit(15, $offset);
    $this->db->order_by('date', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get("postovi");
    return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->result_array() : NULL;
}
}
```

In this model I am missing `WHERE` and the `WHERE` filter is the same as  `$permaData`.

Every filter should reset `$Offset` back to 0 and run Database for that content.

`permaData` starts with "*" before any filter is selected.

Comment: I've reindented your code as it was hard to read. This has brought to light a couple of syntax errors with matching braces, etc. Is this the real code you copied and pasted? Are you seeing any console errors at all?

Comment: no there is more trash everywhere but didnt want to place 100 rows of javascript for adding classes and stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Change your model function to take two parameters instead of one:

```
public function get_next_10($offset = 0, $numbdata = false)
```

and then just call it like:

```
$new_rows = $this->postovi_model->get_next_10($offset, $numbdata);
```

while `numbdata` would be (you're passing that via the AJAX call anyway):

```
$numbdata = $this->input->post('numbdata');
```

and finally, just add the WHERE clause in the model.

Comment: will this also reset offset counter if $numbdata is changed ?

Comment: It returns empty query :/ by that i mean it goes to response === " "

Comment: Then some of the data is not what you expect it to be, check it.